# Equivariant homotopy vs homotopy of fixed points

Tags: algebraic-topology, equivariant-maps, equivariant-topology

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff group and $X, Y$ two $G$-spaces. Assume that $f,g:X\to Y$ are two $G$-maps which are $G$-homotopic. If we consider the fixed point functor $(\cdot)^H$ for a (closed) subgroup $H$ of $G$ then it is clear that $f^H, g^H$ are homotopic.

Does the converse hold? I.e. assume that $f,g:X\to Y$ are two $G$-maps such that $f^H, g^H$ are homotopic for all closed subgroups $H$ of $G$. Does it follow that $f,g$ are $G$-homotopic? Can we construct an equivariant homotopy from non-equivariant homotopies of fixed points? If not then what if we additionally assume that $G$ is compact or even finite?

Comment: The first claim is clear since a $G$-homotopy will preserve the fixed points sets of $X$. The converse is clear as you can take $H=e$ to be trivial, in which case $X^e=X$.

Comment: @Tyrone Note that for $H=e$ you get a **non**-equivariant homotopy, i.e. $f, g$ are homotopic (but not necessarily $G$-homotopic). I don't know how to build (if it exists) an equivariant homotopy from all of that data.

Comment: @MikeMiller What do you mean by "homotopies (...) are compatible with restriction"?

Comment: I'm no longer convinced my comment gives a good answer to your question. Sorry. I've deleted it.

Comment: I think the answer is no, though I don't have a counterexample. Indeed, Benson states as a remark following the equivariant Whithead theorem (6.4.2) in *Representations and cohomology II* that it's not the case. No counterexample is provided at that point in the book (I don't know about the rest of the book). It is however true (I think that's what you base your question on, but I will still say it) that if $f^H$ are all homotopy equivalences, and $X,Y$ are $G$-complexes, then $f$ is a $G$-homotopy equivalence